# WordPress wp_get_recent_posts(); how to make it AJAX

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have a program that was made using `wp_get_recent_posts()` and is working on WordPress.

I want to make it AJAX, so the page will work faster. I don't know where to start and how to make it work.

Code that now I'm using:

```
<?php
                    $args = array( 'numberposts' => '30', 'post_status' =>'publish');
                    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
                    $count = 0;

                    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
                        $count ++;
                        $post_thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $recent["ID"] ), 'loadmore' );
                        $cats = get_the_category($recent["ID"]);
                        $cat_name = $cats[0]->name;
                        echo '
                            <ul class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 post" style="padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">';

                                if(($count%2) == 1) {
                                    echo '<div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
                                    <a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="'.esc_attr($recent[" post_title "]).'">
                                    <img src="' . esc_url( $post_thumbnail[0] ) . '" class="post-image" style="float:left; margin-bottom: 20px; height: auto;"></a>
                                </div>


                                <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
                                <center>
                                <p class="loadmoretitle" style="color:#ccc; font-size: 14px; font-weight: 600;">'. $cat_name .'</p>
                                <a class="loadmoretitle" href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" style="color:#000; font-size: 22px; font-weight: 800;">' . $recent["post_title"] .'</a>
                                </br>
                                <p class="dateload" style="margin-top: 5px; color: #ccc; margin-bottom: 25px;"><i class="fa fa-calendar" style="padding-right: 5px;"></i>' . date("Y m d", strtotime($recent[post_date])) . '</p>
                                <p style="margin-top: 10px; color: #444; padding-bottom: 25px; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;">' .  wp_trim_words( $recent['post_excerpt'], 80) . '</p>
                                    <a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Skaityti daugiau" class="blog-post-button">' . "SKAITYTI DAUGIAU" . '
                                    </a>
                                </center>
                                </div>';
                                }
                                else {
                                    echo '<div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
                                    <center>
                                    <p class="loadmoretitle" style="color:#ccc; font-size: 14px; font-weight: 600;">'. $cat_name .'</p>
                                    <a class="loadmoretitle" href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" style="color:#000; font-size: 22px; font-weight: 800;">' . $recent["post_title"] .'</a>
                                    </br>
                                    <p class="dateload" style="margin-top: 5px; color: #ccc; margin-bottom: 25px;"><i class="fa fa-calendar" style="padding-right: 5px;"></i>' . date("Y m d", strtotime($recent[post_date])) . '</p>
                                    <p style="margin-top: 10px; color: #444; padding-bottom: 25px; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;">' .  wp_trim_words( $recent['post_excerpt'], 80) . '</p>
                                        <a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Skaityti daugiau" class="blog-post-button">' . "SKAITYTI DAUGIAU" . '
                                        </a>
                                    </center>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
                                        <a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="'.esc_attr($recent[" post_title "]).'">
                                        <img src="' . esc_url( $post_thumbnail[0] ) . '" class="post-image" style="float:left; margin-bottom: 20px; height: auto;"></a>
                                    </div>';
                                }
                                ?>
                            </ul><?php
                    }
                ?>
```

Comment: @pegla no, it's not

Comment: Your question is too broad and you are trying to make others do work for you. Basically what you need is same thing on that question (check question - not answer carefully you will find one very useful link there) this might not be exact solution for your problem, but I would advise you to try and implement first fetch next posts with ajax (which is on that link and in answer), check how it works, then implement your solution. And then when you get into coding problem, find specific question you want to ask not just I want ajax on my code, if people see that you tried something they will help.